# how to delete specific numeric after words in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I need help to delete specific numeric after 3 words for the example :

ABC1,A1,6,1

how to get the result like this

ABC,A1,6,1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out.

1. Press `Ctrl+H` to open Replace Windows.
2. Put in Find what: `\b([a-zA-Z]{3})([0-9])\b`
3. Put in Replace with: `$1`
4. In Search Mode, check in Regular Expression.
5. Press Replace All.

Like this.

[image]

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: it works for 1 digit after ABC, but how if ABC12 and ABC123

Comment: If you want to remove all digits after ABC, try this: \b([a-zA-Z]{3})([0-9]+)\b

Comment: not at all, example ABC12,A1,6,1 to ABC,A1,6,1 and ABC123,A1,6,1 to ABC,A1,6,1

Comment: It works on my machine. So, what is the result when you run it?